# Django : Unable to access values from a dictionary nested inside another dictionary

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have dictionary item of the form

```
data = {0:'Karthik',
    1:{'semester':1,'marks':100,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'},
    2:{'semester':2,'marks':98,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'},
    3:{'semester':3,'marks':99,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'}}
```

and i am passing the above data to a template as below:

```
def showAvailableNonCBCSResults(request,usn):
    data = {0:'Karthik',
        1:{'semester':8,'marks':100,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'},
        2:{'semester':8,'marks':100,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'},
        3:{'semester':8,'marks':100,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'}}
    return render(request,'result/showresult.html',{'data':data,'dictentries':range(0,len(data))})
```

Template code is below:

```
{% for i in dictentries %}
     <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover pt-3" style="margin:auto;">
     {{ data.i.html }}
     </table>
{% endfor %}
```

The data from the html field of dictionary is not getting printed. If i use
`data.1.html` or `data.2.html`, it is working fine and i can see the html data. However, using `data.i.html` inside the for loop does not print anything.

Where am i going wrong?

**EDIT 1:**
I made the first dictionary at the 0th index to be of same format as other entries. Still no changes in the template output.

```
data = {1:{'semester':0,'marks':100,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'},
        1:{'semester':1,'marks':100,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'},
        2:{'semester':2,'marks':98,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'},
        3:{'semester':3,'marks':99,'result':'pass','html':'HTML DATA HERE'}}
```

Comment: because at 0th index of your data, there is no nested dict.

Comment: keep the format of the dict same and you wont have any problems.

Comment: maybe start range from 1, range(1, len(data)) since 0 index is just name

Comment: I tried making the dictionary at the 0th index to be of same format as other entries. But still there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

It is encountering an error when trying to iterate through the dictionary, your first entry is not a nested dictionary so when you are trying to iterate as if it was you are running into an error:

```
~ λ python3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 29 2018, 20:13:13)
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> testDict = {0:"Name",1:{"nested":"dict1"},2:{"nested2":"dict"}}
>>> for k,v in testDict.items():
...     print(k,v)
...
0 Name
1 {'nested': 'dict1'}
2 {'nested2': 'dict'}
>>> for k,v in testDict.items():
...     for k2,v2 in v.items():
...             print(k2,v2)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

This is basically saying you are trying to treat a string as a dict, which naturally won't work. You could probably get away with changing

```
'dictentries':range(0,len(data))
```

to

```
'dictentries':range(1,len(data))
```

Since then it will not try to treat the first dictionary entry value as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

I change the for loop in the template as below:

```
{% for k,v in data.items %}
     <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover pt-3" style="margin:auto;">
     {{ v.html }}
     </table>
{% endfor %}
```

I can now easily access the values of nested dictionaries.